# web scraping for betting odds that may be queried

Tags: python, web

I am trying to write something (in python but don't think that matters) to webscrape odds from various websites. 
It occurs to me that actually given that the odds can change at any time, the displayed odds are probably being queried from some or other database. 
Does this render the idea impossible. 
Below an example from the 'inspect element' which is the area where the odds for Liverpool would be expected to be displayed in a perfect world.

Liverpool id="desc_price_input_93457997_1_1-1"> Liverpool

Comment: what exactly is your question? and what have you tried?

Comment: Minterm has described the question better than I did. So far I have been through  a Packt Pub  'Introduction to webscraping with Python ' course and then tried to hit the website.

Comment: Minterm has described the question better than I did. So far I have been through  a Packt Pub  'Introduction to webscraping with Python ' course and then tried to hit the website.  It's obvious to me now  the informaiton i'm trying to get to is possibly in the JavaScript as mentioned.  The question - is it actually possibly at all to get this type of information from a web page.  The website is www.sportsbet.co.za https://www.sportsbet.co.za/index.php?cPath=93109&event_id=ALL&market_type_id=-&country_id=254&rd=1502477100 however if an inappropriate question, i dont want to cause any hassles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if you can retrieve the odds from a webpage's HTML, but that the odds you are looking for often change. If they update, then it is probably due to some JavaScript, which may not be in the HTML that you scrape. However, if you manually inspect the JavaScript, maybe you can find the location where the new data is coming from and instead scrape that location.

If you provide a specific example, I can try to help more.

**UPDATE WITH THE EXAMPLE PROVIDED**

I can see the numbers you want in the HTML of the website you provided. Right click on the page (in Chrome) and click "View page source". Then, search through the HTML for the numbers you want. It may be tricky to parse through the HTML in your code, but it's doable. 
If these numbers update, you will also want your Python code to update frequently. You can do this by simply rescraping the page periodically.